# Laravel 5.1 - Service Provider unresolvable dependency

Tags: php, laravel-5, youtube-api, laravel-5.1, youtube-data-api

I want to use the Youtube wrapper service provider from [alaouy](https://github.com/alaouy/Youtube) and I'm getting the following error.

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $key ]] in class Alaouy\Youtube\Youtube

This is my code inside the controller:

```
use Alaouy\Youtube\Youtube;

class UrlController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request, Youtube $yt)
    {
        $yt->parseVIdFromURL($request->input('url'));
    }

    ....
```

In the register method you can see how he access the config file, that code appears in his API

```
$this->publishes(array(__DIR__ . '/../../config/youtube.php' => config_path('youtube.php')));
    $this->app->bindShared('youtube', function () {
        return $this->app->make('Alaouy\Youtube\Youtube', [config('youtube.KEY')]);
    });
```

"php artisan vendor:publish" - has been executed

Comment: The Youtube class has a mandatory parameter in the constructor. It seems that your object is tried to be instantiated without that parameter..

Comment: Yess it needs the API key, but i placed the API key in the provided configuration file, which I made like this: php artisan vendor:publish

Comment: even if you executed that command you also must edit the `/app/config/youtube.php` file and add your api key there

Comment: I made the changes to config/youtube.php, in the vendor folder not, but config/youtube.php overrides that

Comment: Don't make changes to the vendor config file. They'll be overwritten the next time you update the package. When you publish the config with `php artisan vendor:publish`, that puts the config into **your** config folder - that's where you make the changes.

Comment: yeaa that's what I said / done ;) @Kryten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use Facades.

```
use Youtube;

public function search(Request $request)
{
    Youtube::parseVidFromURL($request->input('url'));
}
```

Thanks to a forum member from: [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/service-provider-unresolvable-dependency)